# Why does RegexTest have a main method?

Tags: regex, scala, program-entry-point, library-design

I wonder why [scala.util.parsing.combinator.testing.RegexTest](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/testing/RegexTest.scala) has a main method.

Aren't library classes intended to be called from within the program and not run separately as an independent executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the only one. One I particularly like is `scala.swing.test.UIDemo`. I really, really don't think they ought to be bundled with the library, but they are. Basically, they are examples you can run directly:

```
scala scala.swing.test.UIDemo
```

Comment: +1 because I agree they shouldn't be bundled.  Maybe bundle them separately with examples, but not with the main library.